# SQL: Search and Replace entry containing a link to a specific other entry in another table

Tags: sql, sqlite

So imagine i have two tables, Car and Driver, with respectively these structure :

```
(hash TEXT PRIMARY_KEY, brand TEXT, driver INTEGER)
```

and

```
(id INTEGER PRIMARY_KEY, name TEXT)
```

So now let's fill our table and imagine we insert into those table 
`("abcdefghi", "Honda",125)` in `Car` and in `Driver` `(125,"Marc").`

What i'm looking for is an instruction that from `Renault` and `Marc` that updates effectively my table to transform `("abcdefghi", "Honda",125)` into `("abcdefghi, "Renault",125)`.

Comment: I can't quite follow your SQL. Could you please edit your question and post the actual SQL you use?

Comment: I use this to simplify my problem and I dont think posting my actual and very complex sql (that i can reduce to this for this problem) will help. What is unreadable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE     Car
SET        brand = 'Renault'
FROM       Car c
INNER JOIN Driver d ON c.driver = d.id
WHERE      d.Name = 'Marc'
```

You would probably want to change 'Renault' and 'Marc' into variables if you plan on running this code frequently with different values.

Comment: But it isn't valid SQLite syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
update car
set
    brand = 'Renault'
from
    car
where 
    driver in (Select id from driver where name='Marc')
```